# How to get all views with its base table information in a query for SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to find the information on base tables for all the view of database in SQL Server. So, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to list all the tables that are used in all views for a database?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit here? What are you expecting for output?

Comment: `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE`

Comment: I want a  viewname along with its base table name/ names (there can be multiple base tables/ views) for all the views in a specific database